# How to parse list of links from text file and do download?

Tags: windows, download, http

I have a text file with links to jpeg files, one link on a row.

I have Windows 10, I can install helper tools if needed.

**What's the easiest way to download all those files ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with any script, it can always be improved for resiliency, but at a minimum, the following 3 lines of PowerShell should get you going:

```
foreach($line in Get-Content .\links.txt) { 
  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $line -OutFile $(Split-Path -Path $line -Leaf) 
}
```

It makes the following assumptions:

1. The file links.txt contains one URI per line.
2. links.txt is in the same directory as the script.
3. All lines in links.txt have a URI.
4. All URIs in links.txt have a unique filename.
5. The file are created in the same directory the script is run from.